# how to change default-target-url depending on user role

Tags: spring-security

I use spring security for user authentication. In security.xml I have

```
<form-login login-page="/login" 
                default-target-url="/dashboard" 
                always-use-default-target="false"  
                authentication-failure-url="/login/error" 
                login-processing-url="/j_security_check"/>
```

I want to be able to configure different target urls for different user roles.  How do i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Spring-Security 3.0 or higher implementing your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is the way to go:

```xml
<sec:form-login ... authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"/>
...
<bean id="successHandler" class="de.....MySpecialAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
```

Then `MySpecialAuthenticationSuccessHandler` can extend one of the default handlers like `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` though they are not really inheritance-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

see -

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=93541

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can configure this, but your `default-target-url` ***dashboard*** can contain logic to redirect to appropriate page based on the role.

Comment: looks like it is possible by having a custom implementation of the authentication filter - http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=93541

Comment: @hese. Thanks.  +1 for your answer. Learnt something today.